# Фиксированные значения в models django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь сделать модель, которая бы смогла бы при деплое на сервер, сохранить список который я задал.
Но при этом, что бы у пользователя, была возможность добавлять туда свои значения. А так же, что бы пользователь не мог изменить мой заданный список.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

PRIORITY_CHOICES = ((1, 'High'),
                    (2, 'Medium'),
                    (3, 'Low'))

class MyModel(models.Model):
    priority = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES)
```

view.py

```
class MyModelCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

serializer.py

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'priority',
        ]
```

В drf всё отображается корректно , но ввести свой вариант нельзя. Это нужно создавать ещё одну модель, и через неё переопределять MyModel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если читать [документацию, по Django относительно параметра choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices), там есть такой замечательный абзац:

> Note that choices can be any sequence object – not necessarily a list
> or tuple. This lets you construct choices dynamically. But if you find
> yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re probably better off
> using a proper database table with a ForeignKey. choices is meant for
> static data that doesn’t change much, if ever.

Если пересказать суть:

Значение параметра `choices` может быть любым объектом последовательности, не обязательно `list` или `tuple` (самому не приходилось разбираться, поди, речь про генераторы или о чем-то [таком, что делает чувак из enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001986/dynamic-choices-field-in-django-models)). Однако, скорее всего, такой путь будет признан грязным хаком и лучше использовать надлежащим образом внешний ключ. `choices` был задуман только для данных, которые изменяются не чаще, чем никогда.

Как грамотный путь будет выглядеть в контексте примера кода из вопроса:

```
from django.db import models


class Priority(models.Model):
    # Таблицу экземпляров этой модели надо предзаполнить, это можно сделать в файле миграции
    # Придется предусмотреть логику, чтобы предзаполненные элементы нельзя было изменять/удалять кому ни попадя
    level = models.IntegerField()  # 1,2,3...
    name = models.IntegerField()  # High, Medium, Low...


class MyModel(models.Model):
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```